# Php error only get a value in array?

Tags: php

I have a sample code:

```
$link = array('google.com', 'facebook.com');
$name = array('google', 'facebook');

$data = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($link); $i++) {
   $data['name'] = $name[$i];
   $data['link'] = $link[$i];
}
print_r($data);
```

=> result on show `Array ( [name] => facebook [link] => facebook.com )`  , not show all, how to fit it ?

Answer (score 1):

The variable `$data` should be a multi-dimensional array. Otherwise, the latest data overwrites the previous one.
Try this.

```
$link = array('google.com', 'facebook.com');
$name = array('google', 'facebook');

$data = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($link); $i++) {
   $data[] = array(
        'name' => $name[$i],
        'link' => $link[$i]
   );
}
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$data[$i]['name'] = $name[$i];
$data[$i]['link'] = $link[$i];
```

out:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => google
            [link] => google.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => facebook
            [link] => facebook.com
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

keep it simple, all you're doing is combining two arrays into an associative array, so use the native functionality of php.  Using a loop to do this is a performance hit and unnecessary unless you plan on displaying the count.

```
<?php
    $names = array('google', 'facebook');
    $links = array('google.com', 'facebook.com');
    $data = array_combine($names, $links);
    print_r($data);
?>
```

result:
Array ( 
    [google] => google.com 
    [facebook] => facebook.com 
)

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
   $data[$i]['name'] = $name[$i];
   $data[$i]['link'] = $link[$i];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0; $i<count($link); $i++) {
   $data[] = array('name' => $name[$i], 'link' => $link[$i]);
}
```

or:

```
foreach ($link as $index => $url) {
    $data[] = array('name' => $name[$index], 'link' => $url);
}
```

another good solution is to go with [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
array_combine($name,$link);
```

result of applying `array_combine`:

```
array (
  'google' => 'google.com',
  'facebook' => 'facebook.com',
)
```